# iPhone - Accessing dynamic controls after creation

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I'm creating a number of UITextFields dynamically based on fields in the database (inside ViewDidLoad) and would like to know how I can refer to the text fields later?

Normally in Interface Builder I would set an Outlet and then refer to the outlet when I need it, do I need to do the same programmatically?

If not, can I add them to a collection and then loop through them instead?

I'm using **MonoTouch**, but interested to know how you'd do this the **Obj-C** way as well.

Many Thanks,

M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the tag value, then access it using

```
UITextField *tf=(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:tagValue];
```

Comment: This answer is better them mine.

Comment: Ah cool so the MonoTouch way would be `UITextField tf = (UITextField)this.View.ViewWithTag(tagValue)`. Awesome thanks a lot dude!

Comment: Does the tag have to be unique across the whole view hierarchy, or only within its parent?

Answer (score 0):

You can tag them and store them in array and then loop by the tag.

Comment: OK I see I can set the `Tag` property, how do I then get an object via its tag? Keen to elaborate a bit more?